# Two inputs per line, after select tag blank space

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a basic form, that I'm trying to get two inputs per line.  Unless the 'province' select tag is floated right, it breaks the spacing. If it's 5th, like in the code I posted, there becomes a blank spot between Postal Code and Fax. The tab order even remains correct (phone -> fax -> email -> web).

[image]

Where if it's floated right (6th in this screenshot) everything spaces fine.

[image]

My form:

```
<form id="form" action="submit.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="first_name">* First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="last_name">* Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="address">Company Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="province">Province:</label>
            <select name="province" id="province">
                <option value="">Select location</option>
                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                <option value="NT">Nunavut</option>
                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
                <option value="US">(US State)</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="postal_code">Postal Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="phone">* Phone:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="fax">Fax:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="fax" id="fax" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">E-Mail Address:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="web_address">Website Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="web_address" id="web_address" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And my CSS:

```
fieldset p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}

fieldset p:nth-of-type(even){
    float:right;
}
```

And if I remove the 'province' select tag everything spaces fine. With the province list, it always breaks the second 'float: right' after the select tag. Is there something wrong with my select tag? Or is it something with my CSS?

JSFiddles:
First screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/sB2W7/
Second screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/4CfQ5/

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle in order to receive more/quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LLJ6Z/2/

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    display
}
input, select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```